How To Check Collision In Godot 4?
I am making a 2D game where I need to check if any "specific" object is colliding with another "specific" object in order to change it's behavior. I know that you can check collisions with Area2D but what if I wanted to change the behavior of the object based on the objects it's colliding with?
Like:
if colliding with A:
    color = yellow
else:
    color = white


You could do this by using Groups and the _on_body_entered signal. If body A has the Area2D, then all the bodies you want to check can be assigned into groups. For example, a player in an asteroids type game might want to check for a collision with a rock, so all the rocks could be assigned into a "Rocks" group. A script using _on_body_entered signal on the players Area2D could do the following:
extends Area2D

func _on_body_entered(body: Node) -> void:
    #check if the colliding body is in the group we want to monitor
    if body.is_in_group("Rocks"):
        # we can alter one of our own variables
        shield -= 10

        # we can call one of our own functions
        do_this_function()

        # we can change the colour of the colliding body e.g to red
        body.modulate = ("red")

        # we can change our colour e.g to red
        self.modulate = ("red")

        # we can call a function the colliding body has
        body.explode()
            
        # if you only want to register the first hit
        # then the collision shape needs to be disabled
        $CollisionShape2D.set_deferred("disabled", true)

    else:
        do_something_else_here_if_needed

